# Pronunciation of K.I.S.S

Tags: acronyms

How would a native speaker of (American) English, especially one working in software development, pronounce the word “K.I.S.S.” (referring to [the K.I.S.S. principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) ?

I guess pronouncing it either as an acronym or as one word (“kiss”) are both acceptable but I would like to know which one is more common.

Comment: Explicitly spelling it out makes the meaning more clearer. However, in most cases, I have observed people go with `kiss` to gain the listener's attention.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Hgz-q76KtQ

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary, sounds like an answer

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but explicitly spelling it out makes the meaning more clearer. However, in most cases, I have observed people go with `kiss` to gain the listener's attention before explaining it further.